# Where is the __bases__ attribute defined?

Tags: python

​‫I define a python class in python interpreter

```
class A:
    pass
```

I get base class of A using A.__bases__, it shows

```
(object,)
```

but when I enter dir(A),  the output don't contain __bases__ attribute, then I try dir(object),  __bases__ is not found either, where does the __bases__ come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__bases__` attribute in a class is implemented by a descriptor in the metaclass, `type`. You have to be a little careful though, since `type`, as one of the building blocks of the Python object model, is an instance of itself, and so `type.__bases__` doesn't do what you would want for introspection.

Try this:

```
descriptor = type.__dict__['__bases__']
print(descriptor, type(descriptor))
```

You can reproduce the same kind of thing with your own descriptors:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    @property        # a property is a descriptor
    def foo(cls):
        return "foo"

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    pass
```

Now if you access `MyClass.foo` you'll get the string `foo`. But you won't see `foo` in the variables defined in `MyClass` (if you check with `vars` or `dir`). Nor can you access it through an instance of `MyClass` (`my_obj = MyClass(); my_obj.foo` raises an `AttributeError`).

Comment: every class is an instance of type, but why is `__bases__` not inherited by `A`

Comment: You're confusing being an instance with being a subclass. Let me add an example with a custom metaclass and descriptor and you'll see the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

it is a special attribute akin to `__name__` or `__dict__`. While the result of function `dir` actually depends on the implementation of `__dir__` function.

You might want to look it on the doc here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html